# How to detect the application is about to terminate?

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-xe2

I'm working on a VCL application which communicates over bluetooth with a microcontroller and I want to execute a code right before the application terminates.

How can I detect the application is about to terminate ?

Comment: Does it have to be the click on the closing button ? I'm asking because you can close the form also with a keyboard shortcut (or from the system menu). And just for being sure, are you asking how to detect when the user closes the main form ?

Comment: It has to be because the user may click the closing button and I want to deal with that possibility. About the question about closing the main form, yes, I want to detect that.

Comment: Really ? So only if the user clicks the close button, not if they press ALT + F4, or close the window from the system menu ? That's a bit weird because you want to execute some code before the app. exits and that should IMHO include all the ways the form can be closed.

Comment: I think I didn't explain well, I want to execute the code if the form is closed in other ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a handler for the [`OnClose`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.OnClose) event of your main form. The reference describes the app. shutdown notification as:

> When the application shuts down, the main form receives an OnClose
>   event, but any child forms do not receive the OnClose event.

The code will be executed when the form is closed by any means (other than the process being killed or segfaulting etc.)

Comment: Thank you, I managed to do it now. Thanks TLama too for trying to help me.

Comment: The `OnClose` event is not called when a Form is "closed by any means". It is only called when the Form's `Close()` method is called, such as in response to the `WM_CLOSE` and ` `WM_SYSCOMMAND:SC_CLOSE` messages. `OnClose` is not called if `Application->Terminate()` is called, or when Windows is shut down. In the latter case, but not the first case, you will get an `OnCloseQuery` event, though. To handle Windows shutdown, you have to catch the `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` message. If you really need to handle all possible terminations, the Form's destructor would be a better choice.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Beware, however, that Form's destructor is called _after_ main() function returns. Some actions are already impossible at that stage, for example, any thread started with std::thread _must_ complete before main() returns.